# How can I convert a table with a modified timestamp ordered by timestamp into a one that specifies start and end dates?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table that contains conversion rate data, but it doesn't include it for every day. It only includes dates when the conversion rate values where changed, but I have transaction records which have the transaction date and the sales price in the local currency. I need to convert the value on the transaction record to a value in USD.

```
# Id    IsoCode ConversionRate  DecimalPlaces   IsActive    IsCorporate CreatedDate CreatedById LastModifiedDate    LastModifiedById    SystemModstamp
01L33000000V0YOEA0  AUD 1.45201 2   1   0   2017-04-05 14:21:48 00540000002oSEHAA2  2022-10-04 08:38:55 0054y000006yQSZAA2  2022-10-04 08:38:55
01L400000007MRmEAM  CAD 1.3015  2   1   0   2010-03-19 08:45:34 00540000000vr6aAAA  2022-10-04 08:38:55 0054y000006yQSZAA2  2022-10-04 08:38:55
01L400000007MRrEAM  EUR 1.00827 2   1   0   2010-03-19 08:46:01 00540000000vr6aAAA  2022-10-04 08:38:55 0054y000006yQSZAA2  2022-10-04 08:38:55
01L400000007MRwEAM  GBP 0.84991 2   1   0   2010-03-19 08:46:14 00540000000vr6aAAA  2022-10-04 08:38:55 0054y000006yQSZAA2  2022-10-04 08:38:55
01L40000000V04sEAC  USD 1   2   1   1   2010-03-18 17:06:17 005400000011UaDAAU  2010-03-18 17:06:17 005400000011UaDAAU  2010-03-18 17:06:17
01L33000000V0YOEA0  AUD 1.46488 2   1   0   2017-04-05 14:21:48 00540000002oSEHAA2  2023-04-03 08:37:46 0054y000006yQSZAA2  2023-04-03 08:37:46
01L400000007MRmEAM  CAD 1.35415 2   1   0   2010-03-19 08:45:34 00540000000vr6aAAA  2023-04-03 08:37:46 0054y000006yQSZAA2  2023-04-03 08:37:46
01L400000007MRrEAM  EUR 0.93892 2   1   0   2010-03-19 08:46:01 00540000000vr6aAAA  2023-04-03 08:37:46 0054y000006yQSZAA2  2023-04-03 08:37:46
01L400000007MRwEAM  GBP 0.82617 2   1   0   2010-03-19 08:46:14 00540000000vr6aAAA  2023-04-03 08:37:46 0054y000006yQSZAA2  2023-04-03 08:37:46
```

My solution for this problem is to take the conversion rate data (shown above) and instead of having just a LastModifiedDate, it would include a StartDate and EndDate, but I don't know how to do this.

How can I accomplish this? I assume it's possible using a row window function sorted by timestamp, but I don't know how to write the subsequent join so that it would link up on the row value.

Edit:
So this is pretty close

```
with recursive cte_currency as
(SELECT DISTINCT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IsoCode ORDER BY LastModifiedDate) as Row_Num
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM sf_unprocessed.currencytype) as tx),
cte_currency_2 as 
(SELECT t1.Id as t1_id, t2.id as t2_id, t1.IsoCode, t1.ConversionRate, t1.DecimalPlaces, t1.IsActive, t1.CreatedDate, t1.LastModifiedDate as StartDate, t2.LastModifiedDate as EndDate, t1.Row_Num as t1_RowNumber, t2.Row_Num as t2_RowNumber
from cte_currency as t1
INNER JOIN cte_currency as t2 on t1.IsoCode = t2.IsoCode and t1.Row_Num = t2.Row_Num -1 and t1.Id = t2.Id)
SELECT DISTINCT t1_id, IsoCode, ConversionRate, DecimalPlaces, IsActive, CreatedDate, StartDate, EndDate FROM cte_currency_2
```

However, the result looks like this

````
'01L33000000V0YOEA0','AUD','1.45201','2','1','2017-04-05 14:21:48','2022-10-04 08:38:55','2023-04-03 08:37:46'
'01L400000007MRmEAM','CAD','1.3015','2','1','2010-03-19 08:45:34','2022-10-04 08:38:55','2023-04-03 08:37:46'
'01L400000007MRrEAM','EUR','1.00827','2','1','2010-03-19 08:46:01','2022-10-04 08:38:55','2023-04-03 08:37:46'
'01L400000007MRwEAM','GBP','0.84991','2','1','2010-03-19 08:46:14','2022-10-04 08:38:55','2023-04-03 08:37:46'```

And that's because I don't have any conversion rates from prior to 2022-10-04, in the table. So in that case, I'd like to create another row which includes that as the start_date and the LastModifiedDate.
````

Comment: If you are trying to just fetch the last conversion record for a specific currency and then use it to convert the value from the transaction table, you could be able to do this without actually having to create two new fields `startdate` and `enddate`

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: The issue is that my transaction record might be on March 1st, but the conversion rate was made on February 14th, and then another conversion rate was done on March 17th, and maybe there was even a prior conversion rate on January 4th. I don't know how to get it to match to the most recent prior date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.  First, I made my currency table as a CTE cause it was just cleaner to read and called it cte_base_currency_table.

Next, I added row numbers to each line of the table partitioned by IsoCode and Ordered by the Last Modified Date. This gave me an easy to use index for timestamps that I could then use to perform joins against. I called this cte_currency.

Using cte_currency, I then performed an inner join of the cte_currency table against itself on the currencyCode and the Row Numbers, wuth the condition that right table's rownumber is one greater than the lefts- so now I know which dates are earlier and later in sequence.

This gave me a solution that was close to final, but since I needed to be able to match currencies on any arbitrary date, and the conversion rate table only included entries where changes were made, I needed to have a start date record for currencies. I made that by doing a UNION all on the cte_currency table by manually adding a row where I forced the LastModifiedDate to be January 1st, 2000.  I still had one more problem however, which was I also needed part of the table to go from the most recent currency change until today.  And I did that again with another UNION ALL in the cte_currency_2 table, so that I have a final timestamp record.

```
drop view  misc.currency_table;
CREATE VIEW  misc.currency_table AS
with recursive cte_base_currency_table as
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM sf_unprocessed.currencytype),
cte_currency as
(SELECT DISTINCT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IsoCode ORDER BY LastModifiedDate) as Row_Num
FROM 
cte_base_currency_table),
cte_max_currency_id as
(
SELECT Id, MAX(LastModifiedDate) as LastModifiedDate, MAX(SystemModstamp) as SystemModstamp, MAX(Row_Num) + 1 as Row_Num
FROM
cte_currency
GROUP BY Id),
cte_max_currency as
(
SELECT 
    t1.Id, 
    t1.IsoCode, 
    t1.ConversionRate, 
    t1.DecimalPlaces, 
    t1.IsActive, 
    t1.isCorporate, 
    t1.CreatedDate, 
    t1.CreatedById, 
    current_timestamp() as LastModifiedDate, 
    t1.LastModifiedById, 
     current_timestamp() as SystemModstamp, 
    t2.Row_Num from cte_currency as t1
inner join cte_max_currency_id as t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id AND t1.LastModifiedDate = t2.LastModifiedDate
),
cte_currency_2 as 
(SELECT * FROM cte_currency as t0
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, IsoCode, ConversionRate, DecimalPlaces, IsActive, IsCorporate, CreatedDate, CreatedById, '2000-01-01' as LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, 0 as Row_Num 
FROM cte_currency as t1
WHERE Row_Num = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte_max_currency
),

cte_currency_3 as 
(SELECT 
t1.Id as t1_id, t2.id as t2_id, t1.IsoCode, t1.ConversionRate, t1.DecimalPlaces, t1.IsActive, t1.CreatedDate, t1.LastModifiedDate as StartDate, t2.LastModifiedDate as EndDate, t1.Row_Num as t1_RowNumber, t2.Row_Num as t2_RowNumber
from cte_currency_2 as t1
INNER JOIN cte_currency_2 as t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Row_Num  = t2.Row_Num -1) 
SELECT * FROM cte_currency_3
```